# How to generate random alphanumeric unique characters with specified length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Problem is described below:

1. Generate a unique alphanumeric characters.
2. Length of characters should be 32.
3. Unique numbers may be seeded in the current time to help in the uniqueness of the generated numbers.
4. Alphabet characters must come from this pool: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Sample Output: `445rpxlKYPkj1pg4q8nAy7Ab91zxZ8v1`

I can do this using Java, but will greatly appreciate if you could help me do this on MS SQL or T-SQL.

Comment: Have a look at [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) function that can generate a given number of random bytes, up to 8000. `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(32), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16), 2)` would return sufficiently random string. It will not have alphabet characters beyond A-F, though.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to split the string into separate rows. Then, do a `SELECT` with `ORDER BY NEWID()` for the random sort. Finally, use `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate them back:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT  (
    SELECT TOP(32)
        SUBSTRING(@str, N, 1)
    FROM CteTally t
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS Result
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/493874)</kbd>

The above is more of a generic random string generator. You can modify it to suit your need. If the requirement will not change, you can simply use this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 52 Rows
    SELECT 1 FROM( VALUES
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1)
    )t(N)
),
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E1
)
SELECT  (
    SELECT TOP(32)
        SUBSTRING(@str, N, 1)
    FROM CteTally t
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS Result
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Felix will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I made this generic enough to handle any pool of characters and any output length. The core idea is to take a random sequence of bytes and use a base conversion algorithm to convert a long number into a new representation then translated to a string using your desired characters as its "digits".

For your specific scenario we need about 183 bits, or *log2(52) x 32*, to get to your desired length. Using `newid()` will generate the unique bit sequence but it will only do so 128 bits at a time and a series of values is simply concatenated until there are enough. Then having a value to operate on, the main loop is essentially the same long division we learned from elementary school. The intermediate calculations are kept in place in the `varbinary` array and the loop continues only until enough output characters are obtained. Each iteration determines another low order digit in the new base and this can terminate early since they won't change. The algorithm can't guarantee any global uniqueness if the output doesn't consume at least all of one `newid()`, so make sure *log2(len(pool)) x output length* is at least 128.

The target base, which is ultimately the length of the character pool, can't be more than 256. I hard-coded a limitation by setting the 128-byte maximum length of `@e`. For the question `@e` only needs to be 32 bytes long and it could be adjusted upward or downward as necessary or just defined as `varbinary(max)`. If you need something more truly random you could find another source for the entropy bits like `crypt_gen_random()`. Since uniqueness appears to be the primary concern this answer fits that requirement. And by the way, repeating characters in the pool will naturally open the door for collisions.

This is fast and generic and it can be easily wrapped up in a function. And a more robust implementation would handle these extra checks.

```
declare @characterPool varchar(256) =
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
declare @outputLength int = 32;

declare @n int = 0; /* counter */
declare @numLoops int = ceiling(log(len(@characterPool)) / log(2) * @outputLength / 128)
declare @e varbinary(128) = 0x; /* entropy */

while @n < @numLoops
begin
    set @e = cast(newid() as binary(16)); set @n += 1;
end

declare @b int; /* byte */
declare @d int; /* dividend */
declare @out varchar(128) = '';

declare @outputBase int = len(@characterPool);
declare @entropyBytes int = len(@e);

declare @m int = 0;
while @m < @outputLength
begin
    set @b = 0; set @d = 0; set @n = 0;
    while @n < @entropyBytes /* big-endian */
    begin
        set @b = (@b - @d * @outputBase) * 256 + cast(substring(@e, @n + 1, 1) as int);
        set @d = @b / @outputBase;
        set @e = cast(stuff(@e, @n + 1, 1, cast(@d as binary(1))) as varbinary(128));
        set @n += 1;
    end
    set @out = substring(@characterPool, @b - @d * @outputBase + 1, 1) + @out;
    set @m += 1;
end

select @out as "UniqueString"
```

http://rextester.com/EYAK79470

As one simple test of the algorithm you could just assign a known value in hexadecimal format and confirm that the output (using `012345678ABCDEF` as the character pool) is the same hexadecimal value. In the same way this obviously works with base64, binary and octal.

*Update:* The main loop can be made faster by not having to iterate over more bytes than necessary. I don't know how `crypt_gen_random()` compares to `newid()` in terms of speed or CPU usage so this change might not even be a net positive so I'll just note it as an alternative to explore. You will want to keep the bytes from `newid` on the little end and attach the rest to the front.

```
declare @e varbinary(1024) = cast(newid() as binary(16));
declare @padBytes int = ceiling(log(len(@characterPool)) / log(2) * @outputLength) - 128;
if @padBytes > 0 set @e = crypt_gen_random(@padBytes) + @e; /* big end plus little end */
```

Comment: There is a [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) function that can generate a given number of random bytes, up to 8000. There is no need to call `NEWID` in a loop.

Comment: @Vladimir I noted this in my comments about uniqueness. The chances of collision are obviously low either way but the reason for using `newid()` is to *guarantee* that 128 bits are globally unique however much that is an ultimately a real concern.

Comment: I see. I didn't read the question carefully enough. I didn't think about uniqueness, I was focused on randomness.

Comment: Great solution @shawnt00 will try it. Thanks.